# Пример на bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

[image: пример]

Можно ли организовать такое дело на бутстрапе как на картинке выше, или он тут бессилен и лучше чисто на css?

Comment: `bootstrap` не `css`? :) ну у тебя тут 3 колонки, это `col-md-4` класс вешаешь на каждый блок, и у тебя получатся 3 одинаковые колонки в строке.

Comment: вот пример - https://jsfiddle.net/dh3mLpch/ - использую 24 grid

Comment: @soledar10 жесть, почему не так? https://jsfiddle.net/m8jjgvyr/1/ у вас дичайшая грязь если вы так пишите. Зачем вы делаете непонятные под уровни? когда бутстрап сам переведен новую строку если колонка будет выходить за пределы

Comment: если иконки спрайтом - можно и так

Comment: + если я сделаю лишний div - это грязь?

Comment: @soledar10 да, грязь, тем более див не один, а 3. При этом это на 1 элемент добавляется 3 новых дива, а таких элементов 6, а это уже 18. И причем тут иконки? Они к этом вообще отношения не имеют :)

Comment: использование вложенности на бутстрапе - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понятно, что именно вы имеете ввиду под словами "такое дело", но вот вам пример.

```css
html body {
  background-color: #018287; 
  color: white;
}

.media > .media-body > .media-heading {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 600; 
  font-size: 20px
}
.glyphicon-lg {
  font-size: 65px;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 2px dashed white;
}
.col-ident {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-ident">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-left media-middle">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire glyphicon-lg"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">SOME SERVICE</h4>
        Text text text text text text 
        text text text text text text text
        text text text text text 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-ident">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-left media-middle">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire glyphicon-lg"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">SOME SERVICE</h4>
        Text text text text text text 
        text text text text text text text
        text text text text text 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-ident">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-left media-middle">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire glyphicon-lg"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">SOME SERVICE</h4>
        Text text text text text text 
        text text text text text text text
        text text text text text 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-ident">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-left media-middle">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire glyphicon-lg"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">SOME SERVICE</h4>
        Text text text text text text 
        text text text text text text text
        text text text text text 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-ident">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-left media-middle">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire glyphicon-lg"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">SOME SERVICE</h4>
        Text text text text text text 
        text text text text text text text
        text text text text text 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-ident">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-left media-middle">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire glyphicon-lg"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">SOME SERVICE</h4>
        Text text text text text text 
        text text text text text text text
        text text text text text 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Бутстрапом можно, но не эффективно. Разве что HTML+CSS.
Можешь конечно написать сниппет на 1 блок и спавнить его столько раз, сколько тебе нужно.

Возможно в инете и готовые есть.

Comment: эм, что? не эффективно? на бутстрапе? вы его хоть хорошо знаете?

Comment: Я им неоднократно пользовался, автор вопроса интересуется чтобы сделать как на скриншоте. В его случае бутстрап кроме колонок ничего сносного не даст.

Comment: кроссбраузерную разметку он даст! А вопрос звучит так: `может ли бутстрап так делать?`. Ответ - да, он может и даже прекрасно. И если бустрап подключен к странице, весь интерфейс лучше строить на нем

Comment: Я и не утверждаю что бутстрап - это плохо. Дело каждого как и что делать, бс для более ленивых.

Comment: ух как же вы ошибаетесь :) Готовая технология, это не лень, а прививание небольшого стандарта в верстке, тем более кроссбраузерного. Так что... лень тут совсем не причем. Это как сборщики webpack, gulp, вы что хотите собирать каждый файл проекта руками? Конечно нет. Технология такая же. Автоматизация рулит прогрессом

Comment: Я предпочитаю все делать ручками и с нуля(В процессе проб и ошибок зато учишься), но и Ваше мнение мне симпатично, спорить не буду:)